# \s++ Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I've seen \s++ but I'm not sure what it means. Could you please use an example? (\s means white space)

Comment: As you can see in the answers and comments: It would be good if you provided the particular regex engine this question is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s++` means to match one or more whitespace characters **possessively**.

It’s the same as writing `(?>\s+)`.  The extra plus makes it possessive, like an independent subgroup.

This illustrates the difference:

```
% perl -Mre=debug -le 'print (("a " . " " x 300 . "x") =~ /a\s+\d/ || 0)' | & wc -l
     621
% perl -Mre=debug -le 'print (("a " . " " x 300 . "x") =~ /a\s++\d/ || 0)' | & wc -l
      26
```

I’m counting how many steps the regex engine takes to solve the match.  There isn’t a match though, but it doesn’t know that. It tries a bunch of real stupid things in the first case that the possessive match prevents it from trying in the second.  Once a possessive match has been made, it cannot be backtracked into and recalculated.

Comment: You might want to add that only Java, Perl (newer versions), PCRE (PHP's preg engine, among others), and the JGSoft engine support possessive quantifiers. All of these, along with .NET and Ruby also support atomic groups `(?>...)`, so regexes that use those are more portable.

Comment: @Tim: I figured that since he found it in code running find, it wasn’t a portability thing, it was just not knowing what it meant in that language. I’m unaware of any other meaning of `++`.